# Why can't I increment this `std_logic_vector`

Tags: vhdl

What's going on here? Why am I getting an 'operator argument type mismatch', and what can I do to fix it?

```
--
-- 32-bit counter with enable and async reset
--
architecture synthesis1 of counter_32bit is    
signal nextvalue : std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0 );    
begin

  --
  -- combo
  --
  nextvalue <= value + 1; -- here

  --
  -- sequential
  --
  ff:process( clk, rst )
  begin

    if( rst = '1' ) then
      value <= 0; -- and here...
    elsif( clk'event and ( clk ='1' ) ) then
      if( ena = '1' ) then
         value <= nextvalue;
      end if;
    end if;

  end process ff;    

end synthesis1;
```

Thanks

Comment: For the initialisation of `value`, either `to_stdlogicvector(bit_vector'(X"0"))` or just `X"0"` if the -v93 switch on the simulator is flicked.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can't increment std_logic directly, you need to convert it to `unsigned` and the result back to `std_logic_vector` using the `numeric_std` package.

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all
...
nextvalue <= std_logic_vector( unsigned(value) + 1 );
```

See [How Do Perform STD_LOGIC_VECTOR Addition Using IEEE.NUMERIC_STD](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322172912/http://objectmix.com/vhdl/190708-how-do-perform-std_logic_vector-addition-using-ieee-numeric_std.html) for example.

Comment: Actually its not that fussy, it is in fact very explicit. `std_logic_vector` is just an array of bits, so it has no numerical value. In VHDL-2008 there are two packages called `IEEE.Numeric_Std_Unsigned` and `IEEE.Numeric_Std_Signed` which will let you do arithmetic directly on `std_logic_vector`. I'm not sure if I think this is a good thing since one of the strong aspects of VHDL is the explicitness. But at least it's there if you want to do it in Verilog style.

Comment: Note that VHDL-2008 only adds IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned.

Comment: problem with converting is that you need to convert result back to std_logic_vector as well which is incredibly wordy

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
...
nextvalue <= value + "1";
```

In my case this solution is works!

Comment: Note, `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned` are both non-standard across environments and considered deprecated. It also conflicts with `std_logic_signed` if that also happens to be needed somewhere. They should be fully replaced by the functionality in `numeric_std` which first came out with VHDL 93. This does require a little more code, but is standardized across vendors. With `use ieee.numeric_std.all`, you'd need to write it as `nextvalue <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(value) + 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

One more way is to overload the "+" in this case you can write:

```
function "+" ( a : std_logic_vector; b : integer ) return std_logic_vector is
    variable result : unsigned(a'range);
begin
    result := unsigned( a ) + 1 ;
    return std_logic_vector( result ) ;
end function ;
```

create a package and include this function in that package and this will do the trick . One more thing do include the ieee numeric_std package because it contains the conversion functions.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what the answers already provided, you could rewrite the code, defining `nextvalue` as having `unsigned` data type (below). Note the use of `nextvalue <= to_unsigned(0, 32);` to clear the counter, and the use of `rising_edge(clk)` to trigger off of a rising edge.

```
-- 32-bit counter with enable and async reset
architecture synthesis1 of counter_32bit is    
    signal nextvalue : unsigned ( 31 downto 0 );    
begin

    ff:process( clk, rst )
    begin

        if( rst = '1' ) then
            nextvalue <= to_unsigned(0, 32); -- reset the count
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if( ena = '1' ) then
                nextvalue <= nextvalue + 1;  -- increment the count
            end if;
        end if;

    end process ff;

    -- Concurrent assignment statement
    value <= std_logic_vector(nextvalue);

end synthesis1;
```

This form of concurrent assignment seems to be the preferred method of updating a counter from what I have found in books and online.

Also, if you continue to use the `std_logic_vector` type for `nextvalue`, the preferred method for clearing it seems to be `nextvalue <= (others => '0');` rather than just `nextvalue <= 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is just that, a vector of bits. It means nothing by itself so you cannot expect vhdl to semantically assume that an increment operation will work on it. The other posts here about converting it to an unsigned should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
nextvalue <= value + '1';
```

Dont know if you are really well versed in VHDL. The following syntax ist logicaly correct if you are using std_logic_arith package